# Can I move the "run" task to the map as a panel in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

Can I move the "run" task to the map as a panel in Google Earth Engine?
Since there is no way to export the data without clicking the run button, I would like to move the run button to the map as a panel if possible?

I am looking for a way to not clicking the run button or move it to the map below!

Comment: Does it matter to capitalize the first letters of earth engine name??

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the export command in a function, and run that function using by adding a UI element to the map.

```
var exportToTable = function() {
  Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: sampleFeat, 
    description: 'Example', 
    fileFormat: 'CSV', 
  });
}


// make a function to export on command
var button = ui.Button('Click to Export', exportToTable);
Map.add(button)
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/03a6354ff76d7b0a530ceb17e1f85dae)

Comment: I think that is not possible. For what you want to use this?